# Create Hyperlink

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have no clue how to make this link into a hyperlink in Jquery.  I am new to the language and cannot figure it out.  I have done a lot of research and still no luck.  Here is what I have:

```
content:" <div class='map_dir'><span class='dir'>Get Directions: </span>https://goo.gl/maps/N7fmt</div></div>"
```

How am I able to get the google maps link turn into a clickable hyperlink?

Thanks so much in advance,
Michael

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to create a link using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261687/best-way-to-create-a-link-using-jquery)

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace 
`https://goo.gl/maps/N7fmt` 
with 
`<a href='https://goo.gl/maps/N7fmt'>https://goo.gl/maps/N7fmt</a>`

Comment: WOW! That easy?!? I am embarrassed.

Thank you so very much!

Comment: Nthing to be embarassed...nobody is born perfect.. you will learn soon.
Please +1 and accept answer if it works.

Comment: I accepted answer, however I am not able to +1 cause I do not have enough reputation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the [anchor element ("")](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). I've created an example:

```js
$("div").html(
  "<div class='map_dir'>GetDirections: <a href='https://goo.gl/maps/N7fmt' class='dir'>https://goo.gl/maps/N7fmt</a></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

We're placing a wrapped anchor into the DIV element. 
http://api.jquery.com/html/